# Pivot table to make all values appear in same row, multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query

```
SELECT u.Unit, ut.Month, ut.Num , ut.Denom
FROM Unit u
INNER JOIN UnitTest ut ON u.Id = ut.UnitId
```

This gives the following results:

```
Unit    Month    Num   Denom
1       March    123    50
1       April    325    60
1       May      653    59
2       March    656    68
2       April    469    98
```

And many more units going from month jan - dec.

how would I get the data to display as so:

```
Unit  Jan   Feb   March  April  May June....
1                  2.46   5.41..............
2      .....................................
```

Where it shows the month (Always Jan - Dec, and the year does not matter as it is already filtered) as headers and shows the respective divided calculation from the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Have you read [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: What aggregation do you need? Is there only one row per `Unit, Month` combination?

Comment: I did read that and I think thats what I am trying to use I am just trying to understand how. It is 1 row per unit with Months Jan - Dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. I've used `SUM()` to aggregate, but you might want to use `AVG` or `MIN` or `MAX` depending on your business logic.

```
SELECT
    Unit,
    SUM(CASE Month WHEN 'Jan' THEN CAST(Num AS DECIMAL(10, 2))/Denom ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE Month WHEN 'Feb' THEN CAST(Num AS DECIMAL(10, 2))/Denom ELSE 0 END),
    ...
FROM
    Unit U
INNER JOIN UnitTest UT ON
    U.Id = UT.UnitId
GROUP BY
    Unit
```

Also, you might want to include your table aliases when using your columns in the query. It makes things much clearer.

Comment: Probably want `Num*1.0/Denom ELSE 0.00` to avoid integer math, and maybe a convert as well to limit decimal places...

Comment: Shhh! I was hoping he'd figure that one out himself ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using the `PIVOT` operator you need to do the `Num/Denom` in a CTE/ derived table that is then pivoted.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT Unit,
                [Month],
                CAST(Num AS FLOAT) / Denom AS Val
         FROM   Unit u
                INNER JOIN UnitTest ut
                  ON u.Id = ut.UnitId)
SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT (MAX(Val) FOR [Month] IN ([March], [April] /*...*/) ) AS PVT
```